# Facebook connection logic

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I can connect to facebook and check on my users and link their account with their facebook profile. But I a question about logic.

When the user comes back to my site, and then want to login again (using facebook), do they have to also be logged in to facebook at that point?

I am using the PHP SDK

Answer (score 0):

If they are logged in before they get to your site, the users will directly see contents allowed to authenticated users. The identification information can be stored by the client's browser (cookies, cache, session...) for automatic log in.

Whenever a user is connected through fb services within a session, his credentials are the same on all websites using fb services within this session.

Hope it helps.